# Navigation Drawer lags with an ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

Whenever I add an ImageView to my activity, the navigation drawer in my app lags a lot. It runs smoothly without the image. I am guessing the lag is because the activity keeps getting refreshed as we open the nav drawer. The image resolution is around 1200x800. I tried using a lower res image, but the lag still persists. I am using the Navigation Drawer Activity that comes by default in Android Studio 1.4

This is my xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".HomeScreen"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home_screen">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="Replace with home screen"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        andoird:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@drawable/dinner" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the drawer layout xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home_screen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home_screen"
        app:menu="@menu/home_screen_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And this is the java code for the drawer layout

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
```

Is there a way to avoid this lag?

Comment: i tried to reduce the size of the image (from [here](http://www.reduceimages.com/)) and it worked for me

Comment: Could you tell to what size did you reduce the image? And also if it's too small, won't it be a problem for tabs?

Comment: approx 400 px... Also there is an option of keeping the image of same qualiity... with that option checked there won't be any problem

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention, I am using this pic as a background, so wouldn't 400px look bad?

Answer (score 4):

Compress your drawables by [TinyPNG.com](https://tinypng.com/)

TinyPNG uses smart lossy compression techniques to reduce the file size of your PNG files. By selectively decreasing the number of colors in the image, fewer bytes are required to store the data. The effect is nearly invisible but it makes a very large difference in file size!

Comment: I think your answer is good, but not complete.
I have some lag, even with compressing my images.
But great website, thank you!

Comment: Ok, my images was too big (like 1800x1200), now it's smooth like hell =D thank you

Answer (score 3):

That's problem is beacuse imageview taking a lot memory. 
the solution is this !
make new folder drawable-nodpi.
put your all resources to that folder.
hope this help :)

Answer (score 1):

Let us make things simple.

Convert Image into SVG format from [here](https://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-svg)

Then go to android studio and create a vector asset from this SVG format.

Then change the colors that you like in XML for background usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look for the [MB to KB converter](https://mbtokbconvert.com) tool if you have any JPG or PNG image files.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34980999)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).